# Questions about confusing java, constructors and extended classes

Tags: inheritance, this, extends, superclass, class-constructors

I uploaded a picture of a problem I can't figure out. The correct answers are highlighted, however, I don't know how to work the problem.

I'm very confused, I thought that constructors had to have the same name as the class on both sides of the assignment operator (the equal sign), but on most of these problems they are different.

ex: i'm used to seeing stuff like:
World test1= new World("Whatever");

But on these problems, I see stuff like :
World test1= new State("whatever");

the answers are highlighted orange, the code given is highlighted green.
I would really appreciate any help or hints on how to do this. I've looked around on youtube and google for a while and can't figure it out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA8b6.jpg[Confusing java stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hoigq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the examples, "State" is a subclass of "Country" which is a subclass of "World".

A subclass can be assigned to a variable declared to be of a superclass's type.  This limits the code to treat the instance as though it were of the superclass's type.

Operators like instance of or checkcast allow the code to determine the actual runtime type (in the example, State) and the downcast it the the subclass.